# Copy constructor for a linked list leads to a memory error

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, copy-constructor

I'm writing my own linked list class (for educational purposes) and here it is:

**My code**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT(x) #x << " = " << x << " "

struct ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode* next = nullptr;
  ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};

class LinkedList {
private:
  ListNode* _head;
  unsigned long long int _size;
public:

  LinkedList() :_head(nullptr), _size(0) {}

  LinkedList(ListNode* _h) :_head(_h), _size(0) {
    ListNode* node = _head;
    while (node != nullptr) {
      _size++;
      node = node->next;
    }
  }

  // Copy constructor
  LinkedList(const LinkedList& obj) {
    ListNode* node = obj._head;
    while (node != nullptr) {
      this->add(node->val);
      node = node->next;
    }
  }

  ~LinkedList() {
    while (_head != nullptr) {
      remove();
    }
  }

  void add(const int& value) {
    ListNode* node = new ListNode(value);
    node->next = _head;
    _head = node;
    _size++;
  }

  int remove() {
    int v = _head->val;
    ListNode* node = _head;
    _head = _head->next;
    delete node;
    _size--;
    return v;
  }

  void print() {
    if (size() == 0) {
      cout << "List is empty" << endl;
      return;
    }
    ListNode* node = _head;
    while (node->next != nullptr) {
      cout << node->val << " -> ";
      node = node->next;
    }
    cout << node->val << endl;
  }

  unsigned long long int size() { return _size; }
  ListNode* head() { return _head; }
};

int main() {

  LinkedList L;
  L.add(4);
  L.add(3);
  L.add(2);
  L.add(1);
  L.print();

  LinkedList L2(L);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I run this code, I get this **error**: `error for object 0x7fff5b8beb80: pointer being freed was not allocated` I don't understand why. My logic beyond the copy constructor is simple: I iterate over the list I'm copying, which is `obj`, and I add a new element to `this` list, which is the list I'm copying to. Since my `add()` function creates a new element with, well, `new`, I can't see where my two lists share an element which I'm trying to delete twice in the destructor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks okay to me. Can you use a debugger to see which line of code the error comes from? (on Linux, put `gdb` in front of your program when you run it, and when it prints an error and pauses, type `bt` to see the call stack)

Comment: You code is working fine in VS2017, no issue, I am able to run it without any issue. Try to clean solution and rebuild it and check.

Comment: The code looks fine to me so far, are you sure the code you run is the code you compile? Otherwise use your debugger. If you don't know how to use it, it's time to start learning.

Comment: @user253751 I'm using CLion on Mac OS X. I asked a friend who also uses CLion + Mac OS X (her OS version is newer, though) and she said she got the same error.

Comment: `valgrind` screams though: https://pastebin.com/iQapLfsd (I called your program `llmem-clang`)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't know what that all means, I'm only learning things. Could you please tell me what I have to pay attention to?

Comment: Not the issue in this program, but don't forget the Rule Of Three: Give `LinkedList` an `operator=(const LinkedList&)`. Then you might optionally improve the class by following the Rule Of Five.

Comment: @aschepler I'm going to, thank you. I've just started learning structures that require carful memory management. So I will, thanks for the advice.

Comment: While this is not related to the error, it may also be of interest that the copy constructor ends up copying the linked list in reverse order.

Comment: @alekscooper Ok, `valgrind` is a memory checker that ideally should report that it couldn't find any problems. In this case it found two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your `_head` in copy constructor:

```
// Copy constructor
LinkedList(const LinkedList &obj) {

    _head = NULL; // <- Add This

    ListNode *node = obj._head;
    while (node != nullptr) {
        this -> add(node -> val);
        node = node -> next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `LinkedList(const LinkedList &obj) : _head(nullptr) { ...`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm from old school ... ^^

Comment: @TedLyngmo So, I'm from a very very old school ! ^^